# How to connect a mutable to an immutable reacitve object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-composition-api

We have a composable function `useApplicationPreferences()` used in Vue 2 with the Composition API. This function exposes a computed non writeable `ref` called `darkMode`:

```js
//useApplicationPreferences.ts
import { reactive, computed } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { Dark } from 'quasar'

const defaultState = () => ({
  preference: {
    darkMode: true,
  },
})

const state = reactive(defaultState())

export const useApplicationPreferences = () => {
  const setPreference = async (
    preference: {
      darkMode?: boolean
    }
  ) => {
    if (preference.darkMode != null) {
      Dark.set(preference.darkMode)
      state.preference.darkMode = preference.darkMode
    }
  }

  return {
    darkMode: computed(() => state.preference.darkMode),
    setPreference,
  }
}
```

We use this function successfully in another part of the app, just after user sign on. This to get the preferences from the backend and set them in the app. The issue we have is on another page where we have a toggle button with `v-model="darkModeToggle".

```js
// Settings.vue
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useApplicationPreferences } from './useApplicationPreferences'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { darkMode, setPreference } = useApplicationPreferences()
    const darkModeToggle = ref(darkMode.value)

    watch(
      () => darkModeToggle.value,
      async (newValue) => {
        await setPreference({ darkMode: newValue }, { saveToBackend: true })
      }
    )

    return {
      darkModeToggle,
    }
  },
})
```

How is it possible to connect `darkMode` from the composable to the `darkModeToggle` ref in the `Settings.vue` template? The computed property `darkMode` is not writable. but the toggle should use it as value an be able to change its value by calling `setPreference()`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have three options to accomplish this and you should choose the one it fits your style.

**1. Make the ref writable.**

This is the easiest one and I think you are thinking it wrong. You are creating a composable which is only allowed to directly read the `ref` via `computed` **but** your intentions are the opposite. You really want an **opened** ref writable for everyone that could have access to (`v-model`).

**2. Use a get/set computed.**

This is an option but it doesn't differentiate a lot from an opened `ref`. https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#computed

```
const state = reactive({ on: false })

const myComputed = computed({
  get () {
    return state.on
  },

  set (value) {
    state.on = value
  }
})
```

**3. Destructure the `v-model` directive.**

You can destructure the v-model directive into a `value` binding and an `input` event. Example:

```html
<Toggle :value="myComputed" @input="setPreference" />
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Answer (score 0):

Feeling a bit stupid here. Just after posting the question I found the option to `get` and `set` a `computed` property in the [Vue docs](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.app/api.html#computed):

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { darkMode, setPreference } = useApplicationPreferences()

    const darkModeToggle = computed({
      get: () => {
        return darkMode.value
      },
      set: async (val) => {
        await setPreference({ darkMode: val })
      },
    })
```

Comment: Oops I didn't see your answer. Anyway, I gave you other solutions to your problem in my answer. Hope it helps. By the way, I don't know if it's a very good idea to create a writable computed with an async function. It's possible but for the sake of your mental health, I'd avoid such things because it could lead to undesired effects.